# PrintGCCause not providing details when using G1GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am using `java8u31` (oracle) with following GC logging options

```
 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20971520 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+PrintGC 
 -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-PrintTenuringDistribution 
 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
```

MY GC logs look like

```
 2015-08-06T09:44:02.486-0400: 1085394.129: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003136 seconds
 2015-08-06T09:44:02.638-0400: 1085394.281: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0354571 secs]
    [Parallel Time: 3.0 ms, GC Workers: 23]
       [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 1085394281.2, Avg: 1085394281.3, Max: 1085394281.5, Diff: 0.3]
       [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.4, Avg: 0.5, Max: 0.9, Diff: 0.6, Sum: 11.4]
       [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.2, Max: 0.4, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 4.7]
          [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 2.3, Max: 5, Diff: 5, Sum: 54]
       [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 2.2]
       [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
       [Object Copy (ms): Min: 1.7, Avg: 1.7, Max: 1.8, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 40.2]
       [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.6]
       [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 1.8]
       [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 2.5, Avg: 2.6, Max: 2.8, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 60.9]
       [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 1085394283.9, Avg: 1085394284.0, Max: 1085394284.1, Diff: 0.2]
    [Code Root Fixup: 0.1 ms]
    [Code Root Migration: 0.1 ms]
    [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
    [Clear CT: 0.4 ms]
    [Other: 31.9 ms]
       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
       [Ref Proc: 30.1 ms]
       [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
       [Redirty Cards: 0.0 ms]
       [Free CSet: 0.7 ms]
    [Eden: 610.0M(610.0M)->0.0B(606.0M) Survivors: 4096.0K->8192.0K Heap: 892.9M(1024.0M)->287.6M(1024.0M)]
  [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs]
 2015-08-06T09:44:02.673-0400: 1085394.317: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0359503 seconds
 2015-08-06T09:44:07.515-0400: 1085399.158: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002921 seconds
```

This is just an excerpt, for any `GC Pause` (young or mixed) I don't see what caused a GC.  When I use `CMS` it does provide GC cause e.g. here is an excerpt from app that uses `CMS`

```
 2015-08-09T15:15:01.665-0400: 1364453.068: [Full GC (System.gc()) 1364453.068: [CMS: 44751K->44753K(537408K), 0.0816661 secs] 135985K->44753K(920832K), [Metaspace: 37944K->37944K(1083392K)], 0.0818386 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs]
```

Answer (score 0):

> (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)

That is the cause. Eden space filled up and had to be collected (evacuated).

occasionally might see other ones (mixed, metaspace full, humongous allocations, ...), but young collections are the most frequent pauses.

Comment: I understand that but I do see there are GCs happening when application didn't receive any requests at all. As show in the log excerpt from application that is using `CMS`, it explicitly tells me that something is calling `System.gc()`

Comment: a) what makes you think there can't be any GCs when there are no requests b) you did not show anything that indicates that there *should* have been a `System.gc()` triggered collection that's somehow missing c) you only listed a single GC cycle as example, it's hard to draw any further conclusions from that. You think there is a problem, but you're not really showing conclusive evidence.

Comment: My thoughts
c) Yes I only have excerpts of GC logs, my GC logs are 20MB large not sure how can provide it.
b) Absence of string `System.gc()` when I switch from CMS to G1GC make me think that G1GC is not logging that info (which is exactly my question)
a) If my application didn't receive any traffic at all for 10 hours why does JVM goes into multiple GC s during those 10 hours?

Comment: You are suspecting that there's a problem. What i'm saying is that the evidence you provided that there actually *is* a problem is tenuous at best. I suggest you either try to solidify your suspicion or consider that the GC is working fine.